# How does returning an || statement work in java?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm new to programming so I have been working through the exercises at CodingBat.com.  In the Recursion-2 section, there is a problem I wasn't able to solve (recursively) so I looked up an answer.  The found solution contained the following code...

```
public boolean split53(int[] nums) {

return helper(0, nums, 0, 0);
} 
private boolean helper(int start, int[] nums, int sum1, int sum2) {
    if (start >= nums.length) return sum1 == sum2;
    if (nums[start] % 5 == 0)
        return helper(start + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[start], sum2);
    if (nums[start] % 3 == 0)
        return helper(start + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[start]);

    return helper(start + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[start], sum2)
            || helper(start + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[start]);
}
```

What the heck does it mean to return something or something else?!  (Last return statement)  For the code to work is has to be alternating between the 2 values, but I can't find any mention of return an || statement anywhere.

Comment: What is the return type of your method? What is the `||` operator?

Comment: Please search for an understand how conditional `||`, `&&` operators work.

Comment: as you can see, the method returns a boolean.  The result of `helper(...)` || `helper(...)` will get returned.  Easier to picture it if you put imaginary parenthesis ie. `return (helper(...) || helper(...));`

Comment: Did the answers help you?

Comment: Yes, very much!  Sorry for the long delay.  I am still learning the StackOverflow interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return helper(start + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[start], sum2)
        || helper(start + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[start]);
```

returns `true` if either call to `helper()` returns true. Here is the same code written a different but functionally equivalent way:

```
boolean helperResponse1 = helper(start + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[start], sum2);

if (helperResponse1 == true)
    return true;
else {
    boolean helperResponse2 = helper(start + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[start]);
    if (helperResponse2 == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I put in a lot of unnecessary stuff for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Actually `||` short circuits so if helperResponse1 is true it won't bother to produce helperResponse2.. You have explained it as if it were `|` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 1):

This statement returns true if either of the terms is true.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what it means.  It doesn't mean "return either value, one or the other".

The `return` statement returns the result of the entire expression.  That is, the OR (`||`) is evaluated first, before the `return`, then the *result* of that expression is `return`ed.

It might be more clearly written:

```
return (helper(start + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[start], sum2)
        || helper(start + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[start]) );
```

Comment: I said the same thing. Are you sure that it doesn't "short circuit"? If the first one is true, does it even both to check if the second one is true or false?

Comment: Whether `||` performs a short-circuit operation is irrelevant to this question, which is about how `return` works with an expression containing `||`.  However, yes, it does short-circuit.  If the left operand is `true`, then `||` will not even evaluate the right operand; it will evaluate to `true`.  (Conversely, if the left operand of `&&` is `false`, then `&&` will not even evaluate the right operand; it will evaluate to `false`.)

Comment: Ahhh okay I get it now. The short circuit has nothing to do with return; it's in the core operation of `||`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Returns a boolean...

```
> public boolean split53(int[] nums) {
```

`true || false` is `true`, `false || false` is `false`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
return a || b;
```

**does not** mean:

```
return a || return b;
```

It actually means:

```
return (a || b);
```

It will evaluate `a || b`, and then return the result of that:

So if `a` or `b` is `true` (either one, or both, are `true`), it will `return true`. It will only be `false` if `a` and `b` are both false.

The point is: it evaluates the boolean expression first, then returns the value.

---

Edit: You can look at [this test code](http://ideone.com/FnJFYf) for examples on how it works.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's wrong. || short-circuits the evaluation, so once it finds something is true it will stop and not bother evaluationg the rest.

Comment: @RSinghS The short-circuiting has nothing to do with my answer. It still evaluates the expression first, then returns the value. The short -circuiting lies in the `||` operation (but notice I didn't talk about that). It gives the same output, but is irrelevant.

Comment: @mikeyaworski If you do `return mymethod() || mymethod();` and `mymthod` prints a string and returns true it wouldn't be the same as `return mymethod() | mymethod();` which would run the method twice even if the first returned true. For a recursive function it might be the difference of it halting or not.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes I understand that (it might make a difference with his recursion), however, it still doesn't make what I've said wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First we have bitwise operations `|` (or) and `&` (and) and they will evaluate both sides to get the answer. However if you were to do a recursive function with that it would do both sides unconditionally. If you are unfamiliar with *or* and *and* here are the truth tables:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| B     | A     | A|B   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| false | false | false |
| false | true  | true  |
| true  | false | true  |
| true  | true  | true  |
+-------+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+-------+
| B     | A     | A&B   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| false | false | false |
| false | true  | false |
| true  | false | false |
| true  | true  | true  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

While *or* is slightly different than what one would expect *and* is spot on. The fact is for these `true | whatever` is `true` whatever the right side is and `false & whatever` is `false` whatever the rightside is. We don't actually need to know the right hand side in those cases or we don't even need to do the calculation that generates that value either. `||` and `&&` is the same as `|` and `&` except it won't evaluate more than it needs. Below is a small test [you can run](http://ideone.com/9sNQ1Z):

```
class Test
{
  public static boolean getTrue()
  {
    System.out.println("returning true");
    return true;
  }

  public static boolean getFalse()
  {
    System.out.println("returning false");
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    System.out.println( "Doing bitwise or");
    System.out.println( getFalse() | getFalse() );
    System.out.println( getFalse() | getTrue()  );
    System.out.println( getTrue()  | getFalse() );
    System.out.println( getTrue()  | getTrue()  );

    System.out.println( "Doing conditional (short-circuiting) or");
    System.out.println( getFalse() || getFalse() );
    System.out.println( getFalse() || getTrue()  );
    System.out.println( getTrue()  || getFalse() ); // won't evaluate right side
    System.out.println( getTrue()  || getTrue()  );  // won't evaluate right side

    System.out.println( "Doing bitwise and");
    System.out.println( getFalse() & getFalse() );
    System.out.println( getFalse() & getTrue()  );
    System.out.println( getTrue()  & getFalse() );
    System.out.println( getTrue()  & getTrue()  );

    System.out.println( "Doing conditional (short-circuiting) and");
    System.out.println( getFalse() && getFalse() ); // won't evaluate right side
    System.out.println( getFalse() && getTrue()  );  // won't evaluate right side
    System.out.println( getTrue()  && getFalse() );
    System.out.println( getTrue()  && getTrue()  );
  }
}
```

So in your code example what does it mean? Well since it's `||`, which is *or*, if the first `helper` call returns true that would end the method and it will become the result. However if it's `false` it's the result of the other call that becomes the result of the method.

It could have been written like this instead without changing the result:

```
boolean tmp = helper(start + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[start], sum2);
if( tmp )
  return tmp;
return helper(start + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[start]);
```

However the `||` makes it a lot easier to read than this.

Answer (score 0):

Every recursive function needs an ending point. Yours is:

```
if (start >= nums.length) return sum1 == sum2;
```

It will return true or false, depending on (sum1 == sum2).

Refering to the statement:

```
else {return (A || B); }
```

It will get into the first clause, until its return TRUE or FALSE. If it returns TRUE, it is the end of the line. Else, it will evaluate the second clause and return the match (A || B).

```
(TRUE || TRUE) -> TRUE
(TRUE || FALSE) -> TRUE
(FALSE || TRUE) -> TRUE
(FALSE || FALSE) -> FALSE
```